# "Unresolved class" error in in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml

I get an error in my manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shaikhaalothman.playsongservice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".PlaySongService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and it gives me an error at this line:

```
 android:name=".PlaySongService"
```

and the error reads:

> Unresolved class 'PlaySongService'
>
> Validates resource reference inside Android XML files.

I haven't found anything that helps to resolve my error here on Stackoverflow, and elsewhere. Anyone that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is there any .PlaySongService class in your project

Comment: Try to clean your project. (assuming .PlaySongService class is in your project as Nilesh mentioned)

Comment: What's the package of the PlaySongService? It should be com.example.shaikhaalothman.playsongservice, otherwise it won't find the class.

Comment: Please show your `PlaySongService.java`

Comment: Is PlaySongService available in  com.example.shaikhaalothman.playsongservice package?

Comment: i think you have to learn Services how works in android follow link and see what  you are getting miss 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: post your PlaySongService.java file

Comment: try deleting those line and add a new line by selecting instead of typing. I mean when you are typing, they suggest some line of code. Select them.
<activity android:name="com.example.kotlindeveloper.(your activity name)./>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `PlaySongService.java` and `MainActivity.java` in the same package, named `com.example.shaikhaalothman.playsongservice`. It will resolve automatically.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but if it was working normally before, then before you make any changes, restart Android Studio. I was having this same issue and none of the answers would work, it was driving me crazy so I reversed all of the changes I had made to "fix" it in my branch and then restarted android studio and the "error" was gone.

Answer (score 13):

The only thing that worked for me was `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: This one helped me, thanks :)

Comment: Like restart system is a fix for all problems on Windows, Invalidate Cacaches is same in Android Studio. They should actually make this official. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Though this is an older thread, I thought I'd include my steps to resolve this issue should it help anyone:

1. Verify that the line `applicationId "com.domain.packagename"` in the module build.gradle file has the correct domain name entered.
2. Make sure that that this domain name matches your package name under your java folder. An easy way to update this is to go to the settings gear in the top right corner of the Project pane and uncheck "Hide empty middle packages" if it isn't, then right-click refactor-rename the folder with your domain name.
3. Finally, ensure this domain name is also correctly entered in the package tag at the top of your manifest file.

My issue was that the directory under java had the incorrect package name, so I had to change it to match the gradle and manifest files.

Comment: great! my issue solved at point 2, i haved removed java folder. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a path in your "build.gradle" file.
I had the same problem as shown in the picture in the link:
[Unresolved class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DULH.png)

Open the "build.gradle" file in your editor and add a path line to the dependencies, as shown below:
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':theClassPathGoesHere') }

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the solutions above worked because I had already checked that the package names, etc. were correct.

So I took the approach of comparing my activities to a new activity generated by Android Studio.  I'm on Android Studio 3.1.3.  I chose File > New Activity > Basic Activity and the first thing I discovered was the package name it defaulted was red.

I checked, and sure enough my applicationId in my module-level build.gradle file was not equal to the package name of my existing activities.  I corrected that, but it didn't make the error go away.

So, I completed the process of generating the Basic Activity to ensure that I didn't get the `Unresolved class` error.  As I expected, the AndroidManifest.xml entry generated by Android Studio did not have the error.  Meanwhile my existing activities continued to have an error.  So I then compared my existing activities to the generated one.  I discovered that my activities extended the `Activity` class where as the generated one extended `AppCompatActivity`.  So I tried changing from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`.  This generated a bunch of errors I didn't want to deal with, so I changed them back from `AppCompatActivity` to `Activity`.  And suddenly Android Studio didn't warn me about any `Unresolved class` errors anymore.

I'm not sure what's really going on.  I thought maybe something got corrupted in my `.idea` directory, but wiping that out and reimporting didn't solve the problem.

In summary, what seems to eliminate the `Unresolved class` error is: change your activity's java file from extending `Activity` to extend `AppCompatActivity` and then change it back to `Activity`.  That resolved the errors for me.

Comment: Hey, thank you there. Mine was `AppCompatActivity` at the beginning, so I changed it to `Activity`  changed it back to `AppCompatActivity`, which is practically the same as your method.

Answer (score 0):

in the android manifest file in android:name="____" my package name was wrong
so copying my package name from the top of the manifest file stated in package:"____"
resolved my error

Answer (score 0):

Rename package from AndroidManifest.xml with Shift+F6 from "com.example.loa"  to "com.example1.loa"  ...  Then go reverse rename package from "com.example1.loa" to "com.example.loa" ...  That will solve the problem , because Android Studio will rebuild project with new name , then will rebuild project with old name ...

Answer (score 0):

you should check your package within the java activity.
clear the package name and rewrite it according to your project.
example- package com.app.gmail

Answer (score 0):

For me it resolved for me by changing: @mipmap/logo1.jpeg to @mipmap/ic_launcher back again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33671592)